# Echonest echoprint server; can't connect from python

Tags: freebsd, audio-fingerprinting, echoprint

I am trying to set up an Echoprint server. As usual, I followed all the instructions, but it doesn't work.

I started `solr`, then I started the Tokyo Tyrant. But when i try to access the thing via Python scripts, or when I start the Python server and try to access it via HTTP, I get the same error:

```
>>> import fp
>>> fp.ingest({"track_id": "my_track_id", "fp": "123 40 123 60 123 80 123 90 123 110 123 130", "length": "120", "codever": "4.11"})
Connection error. 4 tries left; retrying...
Error re-connecting. I'm going to wait one minute for solr to restart. If it doesn't come back there's a problem.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "fp.py", line 584, in ingest
    host.add_many(docs)
  File "solr.py", line 798, in add_many
    return self._update(xstr, addHandler=addHandler)
  File "solr.py", line 923, in _update
    rsp = self._post(self.path + addHandler + self.invariant, request, self.xmlheaders)
  File "solr.py", line 1043, in _post
    self._reconnect()
  File "solr.py", line 982, in _reconnect
    self.conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 720, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 561, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: getsockaddrarg: bad family
```

Is there any way I could fix this?

PS. I am running it on FreeBSD 8.2, Java 1.6, Python 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you run IPv6?

Did you compile python with IPv6 support?

It seems like you are connecting to a service via IPv6, but something is not IPv6-enabled

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just checked, Python had been compiled without IPv6. I'll report when i reinstall it.